# MKMapViewDelegate: How to identifiy overlay in rendererForOverlay

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, mkoverlay, mkoverlaypathrenderer

I'm adding two different `MKGeodesicPolyline` instances to an `MKMapView` like this

```
CLLocation *LAX = [[CLLocation alloc] ...];
CLLocation *JFK = [[CLLocation alloc] ...];
CLLocation *LHR = [[CLLocation alloc] ...];

CLLocationCoordinate2D laxToJfkCoords[2] = {LAX.coordinate, JFK.coordinate};
CLLocationCoordinate2D jfkToLhrCoords[2] = {JFK.coordinate, LHR.coordinate};

MKGeodesicPolyline *laxToJfk = [MKGeodesicPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:laxToJfkCoords count:2];
MKGeodesicPolyline *jfkToLhr = [MKGeodesicPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:jfkToLhrCoords count:2];

[mapView addOverlay:laxToJfk];
[mapView addOverlay:jfkToLhr];
```

I want to render both of these overlays with different styles which need to be configured in the `rendererForOverlay` delegate method.

```
- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay {
    if (![overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolyline class]]) {
        return nil;
    }

    MKPolylineRenderer *renderer = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithPolyline:(MKPolyline *)overlay];
    renderer.lineWidth = 3.0f;

    // How to set different colors for LAX-JFK and JFK-LHR?
    renderer.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    return renderer;
}
```

My question is what options are there to identify the two different overlays in the above method?

Here's what I considered so far:

1. Subclassing: Not an option because `MKGeodesicPolyline` is initialized through a static factory method.
2. Keep references to the overlays in properties and then compare the delegate's `overlay` parameter against those. This does work but it feels a little clumsy. Also, for more than two overlays this approach would need to be extended by using an `NSSet` or an `NSArray`.

Is there anything else I could do to simplify this? It seems that `MKGeodesicPolyline` does not possess any properties that could be used for tagging.

Comment: This question is a lot subtler than it at first appears - where did you discover that `MKGeodesicPolyline` can't be subclassed? (Just ran into this myself!)

Comment: @Grimxn: It can be subclassed but the default factory method `[MKGeodesicPolyline polylineWithCoordinates: count:]` returns an instance of the base class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One alternative to subclassing is to use [associated objects](http://nshipster.com/associated-objects/). But its use is often discouraged.

A longer, but more stable solution, is to make a custom `MKOverlay` and a `MKOverlayRenderer` that forward most of their implementations to a private instance of  `MKGeodesicPolyline` and `MKPolylineRenderer` respectively. Then you can add a custom property to set the color.